# Are "because of" and "due to" interchangable?

Tags: word-choice

Since they can both be followed by a noun or noun phrase.

> Food prices have increased **because of** higher oil prices.
>
> Food prices have increased **due to** higher oil prices.

Is that always the case?

Comment: "due to" is more formal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I think so.  In fact, the [American Heritage Dictionary](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/due%20to) defines *due to* as "because of".

However, some people object to certain uses of *due to*.  The AHD explains:

> *Due to* has been widely used for many years as a compound preposition like *owing to*, but some critics have insisted that due should be used only as an adjective. ... This seems a fine point, however, and since *due to* is widely used and understood, there seems little reason to avoid using it as a preposition.

But as they say, you can probably ignore these objections.

Also, as Theta30 notes, *due to* is slightly more formal than *because of*.